# How to fix this IndetationError in python?

Tags: python-3.x, indentation

```
from timeit import Timer
timer_obj1 = Timer('list_sum()'),
             'from_main_import list_sum'
timer_obj2 = Timer('numpy_arr_sum()'),
             'from_main_import numpy_arr_sum'
print('Pure python version:',timer_obj1.timeit(1000))
print('Numpy version:',timer_obj2.timeit(1000))
```

this is the code I key in
after run it, shows unexpected indent in line 3
Anyone can help me out, please?

Comment: Please put your code as text with proper formatting. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You closed the parentheses of Timer class's constructor (basically a function), but attempted to insert another argument to it with a different indent. You can't do that.

Do it like that:

```py
from timeit import Timer
timer_obj1 = Timer('list_sum()',
                   'from_main_import list_sum')
timer_obj2 = Timer('numpy_arr_sum()',
                   'from_main_import numpy_arr_sum')
...
```